# iOS: Flip UIImageView into UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Looking to make a custom animation that will do the following:

Start with an image view --> flip horizontally into a tableview that is the same size. It should look like the table view was on the back of the image.

I've tried this:

```
  [UIView transitionFromView:imgView      
                        toView:tbl
                      duration:1
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion:nil];
```

But that just flips the superview which doesn't help. Do I need to implement a container view somehow? It seems like overkill (but that may be because I don't know how to use them).

I'm new to animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a container.

I believe that `transitionFromView:toView` does the same thing as `transitionWithView` with some additional manipulation of the "to" and "from" subviews. The documentation doesn't say this. It is just my conclusion from experimentation.

Comment: You do not need a Container View. You can use a View Controller with subviews for the UIImageView and UITableView. See my answer ;)

Comment: Read the question :) "that just flips the superview which doesn't help"

Comment: Yea I used a container view. It's a lot easier than I expected I just didn't quite understand it at first. But its the exact same solution as I had in the question just now the container is the superview.

Comment: My bad, Timothy. Missed the part about the superview.

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard:

Make sure **user interaction is enabled** on the image view.

[image]

Interface:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

Implementation:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // This assumes a static table with 3 rows; update accordingly.
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];

    // Cell 1, Cell 2, Cell 3, etc.
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Cell %d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

// Listen for touches and call "flipToTable" when the image view is tapped.
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if (touch.view == _imageView)
    {
        [self flipToTable];
    }
}

- (void)flipToTable
{
    [UIView transitionFromView: _imageView
                        toView: _tableView
                      duration: 1
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion: nil];
}

@end
```